# How can I use htaccess to run a template-like php script with a url pointing to a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, I have a PHP script that we're going to call `template.php`, it has all the intelligence I need.

Today I have several files in a folder with names like `name1.php`, `name2.php` and others.
All these files have the same content: `<?php include('template.php') ?>`.

The intelligence of `template.php` uses the filename of the URL to distinguish one file from another.

The problem is that I have to create these files physically, inside the folder.

My question is (and I haven't found anything out there): using `.htaccess` can I make the server run a script based on the URL with a template?

Example:

- Assume the `template.php` file exists in the folder.
- No other files are present in the folder.
- Customer accesses `www.example.com/name1.php` or `www.example.com/name2.php`
- `.htaccess` identifies the file and proceeds with executing the script based on `template.php` and the file name, such as `name1.php` or `name2.php`.

Can you give me an idea or point out where I can acquire more knowledge on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would point all traffic to `template.php`. Then within template.php you can do your execution, then in include the requested file (if it exists).

You could do error handling before or after the execution of the template.php file depending on if you want it to execute based on whether or not the requested file exists.

.htaccess would look something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^template\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /template.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then your template.php

```
<?php
#template.php execution code

$requested_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if( file_exists($requested_uri) ){
    include $requested_uri;
}else{
    #404 or other error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel!
This is how it is working now (and you were really fast with a response!):
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Skip rewriting for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite URLs to template.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ template.php?filename=$1.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition to check so it is not the `template.php` file and rewrite to this file otherwise e.g:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/template\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^templates/(.*)$ /templates/template.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Here we are sending the name of the requested file as a query string to the `template.php` file:

```
<?php
$requestedTemplateFileName = $_GET['name'] ?? 'default.php';
```